# Enable copy for selected rows in NSTableView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, copy-paste

I've read through Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X by Aaron Hillegass about how to do Copy/Paste, but I can't get it to work for an NSTableView.

My NSWindowController has a window with a couple of textfields and an NSTableView. When the textfields have focus, the Copy menu is enabled and I can copy the values (which is all default behavior, no action/code on my part was required).

My NSWindowController has a -copy: method implemented and declared:

```
- (void) copy:(id)sender {
    NSPasteboard *pasteBoard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    // some code to put data on the pasteBoard
}
```

However, when I select a few rows and try to Copy, the copy menu is not enabled and I cannot copy the selected rows.

Is there something else I need to do to enable copy for my NSTableView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem ended up being that my window's delegate wasn't set to be my window controller, so when the window was trying to validate the menu items it didn't know who to check for selectors.

Answer (score -8):

inside the interface builder, make sure that the save menu's selector is connected to the first responder's "save:" action

Comment: Completely silly and wrong - how does that even relate to the question..?